# Couchbase - creating design documents through API

Tags: php, couchbase

I've been using Couchbase for a large project where we only consume data, but have no requrirement to actually write to the Couchbase cluster. I want to write some management tools and be able to create Design Documents and Views through the API and not the web console.

Creating Documents is not an issue at all, but whenever I use setDesignDoc() I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException' with message 'Failed to store design doc: Invalid input/arguments' in ....
```

I can get the actual view data from the source with getDesignDoc() and use it for the creating that design document on the destination server like so:

```
$connandleDestination->setDesignDoc( "myDesignDoc", $connSource->getDesignDoc("myDesignDoc") );
```

And that's where I get the above error message.

I'm using the PHP SDK by the way with the latest version against Couchbase 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if what you've given as your example is the exact code you're using?

```
$connandleDestination->setDesignDoc( "myDesignDoc", $connSource->getDesignDoc("myDesignDoc") );
```

What you've given would not work as, from the [API docs](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.1.5/classes/Couchbase.html#method_setDesignDoc), the syntax is as follows:

```
setDesignDoc(string $name, string $document) : bool
```

Hence, it would appear you are trying to set a new doc, `myDesignDoc` to be equal to the design doc `myDesignDoc`, which would either not exist, or have no effect (as setting something to equal itself causes no change - and creating a new design doc with the name of an existing one will simply overwrite it).

Did you instead mean to just use [`get()`](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.1.5/classes/Couchbase.html#method_get)? `get()` would return a document (which would be valid in the `setDesignDoc` input, and that document could have the same name as the new design doc to be created.

Comment: I'm trying to set a document on the destination server with the output of the source server. hence the connDestination and connSource. I ended up rewriting the whole thing and am now using REST to actually create the views